# aligning multiple divs - left, center and right

Tags: css, html, css-float

My website looks like this:

```
[left div][          center div         ][right div]
          [                             ][right div]
          [                             ]
          [                             ]
          [                             ]
          [                             ]
```

If I try to add another div to the left it looks like this:

```
[left div]
[        ]
[left div][          center div         ][right div]
[        ][                             ][right div]
[        ][                             ]
```

My css:

```
    #left{
    width: 140px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    }

    #center{
    float: left;
    width:600px;
    padding: 10px;
    }

    #right {
    float: right;
    height: auto;
    width: 140px;
    }
```

How can I make it look like this

```
[left div][          center div         ][right div]
[        ][                             ][right div]
[left div][                             ]
[        ][                             ]
[        ][                             ]
[left div][                             ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain the idea: You can't use "clear:left" for the div:left here, because it will make a new line between 2 "left" div.

I think that your best bet is to create the "wrapper": left-wrapper, center-wrapper, and right-wrapper (the same to left,right & center above). Then you can put child-div into "left-wrapper", 100% width, without floating stuff.

Answer (score 2):

you can use something like the following:

**html**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="left"></div><div class="center"></div><div class="right"></div>
    <div class="left"></div> <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
```

**css**

```
   #wrapper {width:886px; overflow:hidden}
  .left {float:left; width:140px; height:200px; background:red;border:1px solid black;}
  .right {float:right;width:140px; height:200px; background:blue;border:1px solid black;}
  .center {float:left;width:600px; height:200px; background:grey;border:1px solid black;}
```

**live example:** http://jsbin.com/eroka5/2

Answer (score 0):

Here is my sample code that achieves this goal.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#left,#center,#right{
width:33%;
float:left;
}
#bottomleft,#bottomright
{
width:50%;
float:left;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div width="1024px"> 
 <div id="left">left</div><div id="center">center</div><div id="right">right</div>
<div>
<div>
 <div id="bottomLeft" >bottomleft</div> <div id="bottomright">bottomright</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```